# ggplot2 - How to set legend for geom_ribbon, geom_line and geom_point with the same color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, alpha

I have a plot that includes geom_ribbon, geom_line and geom_point with the same color. Could you please tell me how I can set a legend that includes descriptions for all 3 types and also considers the alpha values?

Code:

```
predplot <- ggplot(data=AllData, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=AllData$advancedFitLower95, ymax=AllData$advancedFitUpper95, fill="red"), alpha=0.4) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=AllData$advancedFitLower80, ymax=AllData$advancedFitUpper80, fill="red"), alpha=0.7) +
  geom_line(aes(y = AllData$advancedFitForecast), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = AllData$Destatis), shape=21, fill="white", colour = "red", size=2, stroke=2) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(x="", 
       y= "births") + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=11),
        axis.text=element_text(size=11, colour = "black"),
        legend.title = element_text(size=11),
        legend.text = element_text(size=11))

plot(predplot)
```

Screenshot: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt2VE.png)

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 
14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791), class = "Date"), 
    Destatis = c(59612, 54760, 51319, 53869, 55273, 50314, 55486, 
    52020, 56054, 57531, 61918), Google = c(43, 43, 42, 36, 42, 
    42, 38, 38, 36, 36, 37), baseFitForecast = c(59271.9941102255, 
    56055.8996704734, 51255.5683820705, 52555.810279121, 55472.8442207511, 
    50398.5498216408, 53384.0684325976, 51442.6744082598, 54315.656143645, 
    55958.488805051, 60578.2928236282), advancedFitForecast = c(59858.2784132212, 
    56532.8381467247, 52011.5910887163, 53545.5662783686, 55911.0730077498, 
    51096.7453713563, 54158.6688635223, 52311.8612991644, 55214.1783090307, 
    56753.0170022236, 61474.9182990983), advancedFitLower80 = c(57654.4066959064, 
    54356.5696860696, 49851.5946301954, 51409.5599195636, 53771.2991570756, 
    48985.3271962111, 52070.5287242434, 50228.384597234, 53153.27240174, 
    54699.1820518215, 59444.5589990337), advancedFitLower95 = c(56487.7474813286, 
    53204.5227529061, 48708.1615746366, 50278.8264556699, 52638.5713034585, 
    47867.6099304977, 50965.1341063625, 49125.4586539642, 52062.2947154126, 
    53611.9475039649, 58369.7517097918), advancedFitUpper80 = c(62062.150130536, 
    58709.1066073798, 54171.5875472373, 55681.5726371735, 58050.8468584239, 
    53208.1635465015, 56246.8090028013, 54395.3380010947, 57275.0842163213, 
    58806.8519526258, 63505.2775991629), advancedFitUpper95 = c(63228.8093451138, 
    59861.1535405433, 55315.020602796, 56812.3061010672, 59183.574712041, 
    54325.8808122149, 57352.2036206821, 55498.2639443645, 58366.0619026487, 
    59894.0865004823, 64580.0848884049)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Destatis", "Google", "baseFitForecast", "advancedFitForecast", 
"advancedFitLower80", "advancedFitLower95", "advancedFitUpper80", 
"advancedFitUpper95"), row.names = 69:79, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually what the legend to describe?
The color and alpha value is fixed for all data points, so there are no aesthetics to describe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Simon! I fixed the color and alpha values for all data points. Basically I just want to include a legend that shows the color of the 80% and 95% confidence intervals as well as the color and shape of the destatis data points

Comment: Can you provide a minimal dataset, or an example plot based on a common dataset (iris, diamonds...)?   That will enable other people to test solutions instead of just giving 'try this and see..' suggestions

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DonJ! I added a dataset